# How to notice if the device GCM registrationID is expired?

Tags: android, registration, google-cloud-messaging

I know that the `registrationID` of my device is not stable in GCM and it might be expired on google server.

When `registrationID` is expired I should renew it and send it to my GCM server.

My Android app saves its first `registrationID` and use it. How can I notice in my Android app if `registrationID` has been expired in google server for renewing it and sending to GCM server?

Comment: Did you get any result with new `GCM` library? I'm in a same scenario!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)

> Google may periodically refresh the registration ID, so you should
>   design your Android application with the understanding that the
>   `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` intent may be called
>   multiple times. Your Android application needs to be able to respond
>   accordingly.

Also Note:

> The registration ID lasts until the Android application explicitly
>   unregisters itself, or until Google refreshes the registration ID for
>   your Android application.

So you need to update the registration ID on your server when you recieve the `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` intent.

Also you can have a code in your launcher/main activity that checks whether you are registered on GCM as follows

```
String regid = getRegistrationId(context);
if (regid.length() == 0) {
    registerBackground();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no such function or API available to check for it, you need to define the a certain period of time for periodically refreshing it inside the client.